# Loading image from a Java file

Tags: java, image

I have this project structure:

- ProjectName

  - src

    - xxx

      - co

        - com

          - package

            - something.java
  - web

    - image

      - print

        - pic.jpg

I want to load the pic.jpg in the java file which will then be used in the pdf file generated. I have gone through the answers here but, nothing helped me yet. Possibly I am missing a small thing.

If the pic.jpg was under package, then `getClass().getResource("pic.jpg")` works absolutely fine. `getClass().getResource("/web/image/print/pic.jpg")` doesnt work as well. But I want to place all my images under image folder and refer it in the java file.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the application runtime path and rebase the path to the folder which images locate.
You can use the code:

```
String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();// or System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your files are not copied to bin/ directory. Change your build script to copy them to output directory

`getClass().getResource()` will use class loader to load class, since those files need to be in classpath

Comment: This makes sense to me. I have only class files under the build folder. I will try this and let you know. Thanks.